# Como criar um menu com jquery que realize esse efeito após o scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html5

Olá, amigos.

Sou iniciante e gostaria de saber como eu aplico esse efeito em um menu fixo (para desktops) para que que quando o usuário navegue para a section a seguir (depois da section #home) um background surja no menu e ele passe a ter position: fixed (aparentemente), como podemos observar no link a seguir:

http://unbranded.co/glissando/index02.html (navegue até a próxima seção para visualizar o efeito)

Esse efeito é muito comum em Landings Pages.

Já procurei plugins jQuery que realizem esse efeito, mas acredito que eu não esteja sabendo como procurar, pois não achei nada.

Ficarei muito grato.

Answer (score 2):

Ao que parece, ele esta usando esse plugin jquery:
http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/guides/getting-started/
O que ele faz é monitorar o quanto a pessoa fez scroll na pagina (ou 'rolou' a pagina no portugues claro) e aplica uma classe css nele para mudar o background e colocar o position fixed por exemplo:

```
$('#about').waypoint(function (event, direction) {

        if (direction === 'down') 
        {
            $('.header').addClass('solid-bg');            
        } 
        else 
        {
           $('.header').removeClass('solid-bg');   
        }

},{ offset: 100 });
```

No caso dele o id="about" é a parte da pagina que fica logo abaixo do slider dele, então assim que a pessoa dar scroll na pagina do final do slider em diante, ele vai aplicar a class="solid-bg" que tem o seguinte css:

```
.header.solid-bg {
    background: #555;
    top: 0px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    position: fixed;
}
```

É só pegar esse exemplo e aplicar com seu estilo na sua pagina.

Comment: Muito obrigado, meu amigo!